# How to use postgresql any with jsonb data

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

## Related

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308432/how-to-search-within-a-jsonb-column-in-postgresql) question

## Question

I have a postgresql table that has a column of type jsonb. the json data looks like this

```
{
   "personal":{
      "gender":"male",
      "contact":{
         "home":{
            "email":"ceo@home.me",
            "phone_number":"5551234"
         },
         "work":{
            "email":"ceo@work.id",
            "phone_number":"5551111"
         }
      },
      ..
      "nationality":"Martian",
      ..
   },
   "employment":{
      "title":"Chief Executive Officer",
      "benefits":[
         "Insurance A",
         "Company Car"
      ],
      ..
   }
}
```

This query works perfectly well

```
select employees->'personal'->'contact'->'work'->>'email' 
from employees 
where employees->'personal'->>'nationality' in ('Martian','Terran')
```

I would like to fetch all employees who have benefits of type `Insurance A` OR `Insurance B`, this ugly query works:

```
 select employees->'personal'->'contact'->'work'->>'email' 
   from employees 
   where employees->'employment'->'benefits' ? 'Insurance A' 
   OR employees->'employment'->'benefits' ? 'Insurance B';
```

I would like to use [any](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-comparisons.html) instead like so:

```
select * from employees 
where employees->'employment'->>'benefits' = 
any('{Insurance A, Insurance B}'::text[]);
```

but this returns 0 results.. ideas?

## What i've also tried

I tried the following syntaxes (all failed):

```
.. = any({'Insurance A','Insurance B'}::text[]);
.. = any('Insurance A'::text,'Insurance B'::text}::array);
.. = any({'Insurance A'::text,'Insurance B'::text}::array);
.. = any(['Insurance A'::text,'Insurance B'::text]::array);
```

Comment: Would the containment operator `?|` help here? Don't have access to a new enough Pgsql to test it out immediately but something like `?| array['Insurance A', 'Insurance B']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`employees->'employment'->'benefits'` is a json array, so you should unnest it to use its elements in `any` comparison.
Use the function [`jsonb_array_elements_text()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) in [lateral join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html):

```
select *
from 
    employees, 
    jsonb_array_elements_text(employees->'employment'->'benefits') benefits(benefit)
where
    benefit = any('{Insurance A, Insurance B}'::text[]);
```

---

The syntax

```
from 
    employees, 
    jsonb_array_elements_text(employees->'employment'->'benefits')
```

is equivalent to

```
from 
    employees, 
    lateral jsonb_array_elements_text(employees->'employment'->'benefits')
```

The word `lateral` may be omitted. For [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html):

> LATERAL can also precede a function-call FROM item, but in this case
>   it is a noise word, because the function expression can refer to
>   earlier FROM items in any case.

See also: [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/1995738)

The syntax

```
from jsonb_array_elements_text(employees->'employment'->'benefits') benefits(benefit)
```

is a form of aliasing, per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-table-expressions.html)

> Another form of table aliasing gives temporary names to the columns of
>   the table, as well as the table itself:
>
> FROM table_reference [AS] alias ( column1 [, column2 [, ...]] )

Comment: questions: 1. why do you put a `,` right after `employees`? reference? 2. what's this `benefits(benefit)`.. never seen such a syntax before.. reference?

Comment: How to use index on jsonb column?

Comment: @morfair - In general, read [8.14.4. jsonb Indexing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING). Regarding the query in the answer,  there is no index that could support `jsonb_array_elements()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the containment operator [`?|`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) to check if the array contains any of the values you want.

```
select * from employees 
where employees->'employment'->'benefits' ?| array['Insurance A', 'Insurance B']
```

If you happen to a case where you want all of the values to be in the array, then there's the [`?&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) operator to check for that.

Comment: got this error: ```ERROR:  operator does not exist: text ?| text[]
LINE 1: ... employees->'employment'->>'benefits' ?| array['...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.```

see formatted error [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/m4Gie.png)

Comment: It's a typo, see my edit. Should be `employees->'employment'->'benefits'`

Comment: @klin Thanks, realized also it should've been with the other operator